# DEFPUSHBUTTON not defaulting focus to IDCANCEL

Tags: c++, mfc

My resource file contains a DEFPUSHBUTTON for IDCANCEL, but for some reason, they Focus on the button is not changing from IDOK to IDCANCEL.

```
IDD_HEALTHCARDINFO DIALOGEX 0, 0, 256, 223
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Health Card Information"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Yes",IDOK,67,202,50,14
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "No",IDCANCEL,140,202,50,14
```

Inside my OnInitDialog() I've tried to force it by sending a DM_SETDEFID Message Also.

```
BOOL CHealthCardInfo::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    SetDefID(IDCANCEL);
    SendMessage(GetDlgCtrlID(),  DM_SETDEFID, IDCANCEL);
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default button doesn't affect focus.  It affects what button is activated by the ENTER key when some non-button control has focus.

You can use `SetFocus` in `OnInitDialog` (and also return FALSE) to change which control has focus when the dialog opens.  Or you can reorder the controls within the dialog resource.

---

As a side note, a dialog box that asks a Yes/No question generally shouldn't have a title of "Information".

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had to do this and found my resources' Default settings are ignored. E.g. even by setting default for IDCANCEL to YES, and IDOK to NO in the resource editor, my buttons do not reflect the resources. 
So thanks Ben for your insight (and other places) for helping me solve this problem. I thought I'd share my code as there's something extra - you have to return FALSE even if you do **not** set focus!

In `OnInitDialog`

```
// Set the style of the OK button to be BS_PUSHBUTTON.
SendDlgItemMessage( IDOK, BM_SETSTYLE, BS_PUSHBUTTON, (LONG)TRUE);

// Tell the window to make IDCANCEL the default
SendMessage( DM_SETDEFID, IDCANCEL, 0L);

// Tell IDCANCEL it's a default.
SendDlgItemMessage( IDCANCEL, BM_SETSTYLE, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, (LONG)TRUE);

// Set focus to IDCANCEL
GetDlgItem( IDCANCEL )->SetFocus();

// finally, even if you do not set focus, you have to return FALSE for this change of defaults to work.
return FALSE;
```

Comment: I like your clear and understandable approach to solving the problem. However, I suggest that you add the missing parameter (handle to the window containing the control => HWND) for the sake of completeness. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, when I reorder the buttons - put the focus button first, the issue was fixed. Using SetFocus and return FALSE doesn't work.